# extending json schema (for each)

Tags: jsonschema

Here are my json schemas for a "contact" entity and a "detailedContact" entity. The difference between them is that the detailed contact has a metadata object associated with each attribute.

I would like to know if there is a better way of doing this (but still easy to understand), so that I don't need to define all the contact attribute names in two places.

```
    "metadata": { 
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "modifiedAt": { "$ref": "#/definitions/datetime" },
            "modifiedSystem": { "type": "string" },
            "verifiedAt": { "$ref": "#/definitions/datetime" },
            "verifiedSystem":  { "type": "string" },
            "lastInteractionType": { "type": "string" }
        },
        "required": [ "modifiedAt", "modifiedSystem" ]
    },

    "contact": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "id": { "type": "integer" },
            "fullName": { "type": "string" },
            "firstName": { "type": "string" },
            "lastName": { "type": "string" },
            "preferredName": { "type": "string" },
            "gender": { "type": "string" },
            "birthDate": { "type": "string" },
            "nationality": { "type": "string" },
            "nationality2": { "type": "string" },
            "nri": { "type": "boolean" },
            "optOut": { "type": "boolean" },
            "maritalStatus": { "type": "string" },
            "religion": { "type": "string" },
            "occupation": { "type": "string" },
            "prStatus": { "type": "string" },
            "photoFilepath": { "type": "string" },
            "phones": {
                "type": "array",
                "items" : { "$ref": "#/definitions/phone" }
            },
            "emails": {
                "type": "array",
                "items" : { "$ref": "#/definitions/email" } 
            },
            "addresses": {
                "type": "array",
                "items" : { "$ref": "#/definitions/address" }
            },
            "metadata": { "$ref": "#/definitions/metadata" }
        }
    },

    "phone": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "countryCode": { "type": "string" },
            "number" : { "type": "string" },
            "phoneType": { "type": "string" },
            "type": { "type": "string" },
            "status": { "type": "string" },
            "metadata": { "$ref": "#/definitions/metadata" }
        },
        "required": [ "countryCode", "number", "phoneType", "type", "status", "metadata" ]
    },

    "email": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "address": { "type": "string" },
            "type": { "type": "string" },
            "status": { "type": "string" },
            "metadata": { "$ref": "#/definitions/metadata" }
        },
        "required": [ "address", "type", "status", "metadata" ]
    },

    "address": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "addressLine1": { "type": "string" },
            "townCity": { "type": "string" },
            "districtCounty": { "type": "string" },
            "stateProvince": { "type": "string" },
            "postcode": { "type": "string" },
            "country": { "type": "string" },
            "type": { "type": "string" },
            "status": { "type": "string" },
            "metadata": { "$ref": "#/definitions/metadata" }
        },
        "required": [ "addressLine1", "country", "type", "status", "metadata" ]
    },

    "stringAttributeWithMetadata": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "value": { "type": "string" },
            "metadata": { "$ref": "#/definitions/metadata" }
        },
        "dependencies": {
            "value": [ "metadata" ]
        }
    },

    "booleanAttributeWithMetadata": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "value": { "type": "boolean" },
            "metadata": { "$ref": "#/definitions/metadata" }
        },
        "dependencies": {
            "value": [ "metadata" ]
        }
    },

    "virtualDetailedContact": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "fullName": { "$ref": "#/definitions/stringAttributeWithMetadata" },
            "firstName": { "$ref": "#/definitions/stringAttributeWithMetadata" },
            "lastName": { "$ref": "#/definitions/stringAttributeWithMetadata" },
            "preferredName": { "$ref": "#/definitions/stringAttributeWithMetadata" },
            "gender": { "$ref": "#/definitions/stringAttributeWithMetadata" },
            "birthDate": { 
                "allOf": [
                    { "$ref": "#/definitions/stringAttributeWithMetadata" },
                    { "properties": {
                        "value": {
                            { "format": "date" }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            "nationality": { "$ref": "#/definitions/stringAttributeWithMetadata" },
            "nationality2": { "$ref": "#/definitions/stringAttributeWithMetadata" },
            "nri": { "$ref": "#/definitions/booleanAttributeWithMetadata" },
            "optOut": { "$ref": "#/definitions/booleanAttributeWithMetadata" },
            "maritalStatus": { "$ref": "#/definitions/stringAttributeWithMetadata" },
            "religion": { "$ref": "#/definitions/stringAttributeWithMetadata" },
            "occupation": { "$ref": "#/definitions/stringAttributeWithMetadata" },
            "prStatus": { "$ref": "#/definitions/stringAttributeWithMetadata" },
            "photoFilepath": { "$ref": "#/definitions/stringAttributeWithMetadata" },
            "phones": {
                "type": "array",
                "items" : { "$ref": "#/definitions/phone" }
            },
            "emails": {
                "type": "array",
                "items" : { "$ref": "#/definitions/email" } 
            },
            "addresses": {
                "type": "array",
                "items" : { "$ref": "#/definitions/address" }
            },
            "metadata": { "$ref": "#/definitions/metadata" }
        }
    },

    "detailedContact": {
        "allOf": [
            { "$ref": "#/definitions/virtualDetailedContact" },
            { "properties": 
                "id": { "type": "integer" },
                "systems": { 
                    "type": "array",
                    "items": { "type": "string" }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

Note: `virtualDetailedContact` is basically the same as `detailedContact` - except without an `id` and `systems` attribute. (We are making a contact merge application which will suggest the definition of a newly merged contact based on the attribute metadata provided from several existing contacts - so this will not have `id` and `systems` attributes since it doesn't exist yet)

Comment: Sounds like a job for `allOf` and `$ref`

Comment: An example of a detailedContact JSON object would be great to provide a better answer. Do you need *metadata* to be a property name or just the list of nested keywords?

Comment: @jruizaranguren: Have updated the question to show my proposed schemas. Pls let me know if you think this can be done in a better way

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I totally understand the question - or maybe the schema code you included already answers the question you originally posted. Either way, your `detailedContact` is a bit wrong and should be:

```
"detailedContact": {
    "type":"object",
    "allOf": [
        { "$ref": "#/definitions/virtualDetailedContact" },
    ],
    { "properties": 
        "id": { "type": "integer" },
        "systems": { 
            "type": "array",
            "items": { "type": "string" }
        }
    }
}
```

Is your question "can I have an object `detailedContact` which is just like `contact`, except that every boolean property in `detailedContact` is a `"$ref": "#/definitions/booleanAttributeWithMetadata"` and so on?"

If so, I can't think of any way to do that.

Comment: I thought the "allOf" construct is supposed to contain an array of the schemas which we need to combine - as described here: http://spacetelescope.github.io/understanding-json-schema/structuring.html#extending . My question is - "Is there any way of doing this where I don't need to define all the attributes in two places". e.g. If I add a new attribute like "passportNumber" then I should only need to add it to one schema.

Comment: You need to "define all the attributes in two places" because they're basically completely unrelated attributes that just happen to have the same name.